# Axis in R plot how to get Λ

Tags: r, plot, axis

Using

```
ylab = bquote(lambda(t))
```

in the moment to get a lambda to the y-axis of the plot but this is the small not the large Λ.

How can I get Λ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do it capitalize the `l` in `lambda`.

```
plot(1, ylab = bquote(Lambda(t)))
```

[image]